# Android how to use AlarmManager and a Service Class to schedule a repeating method from another activity

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I'm trying to use and broadcast receiver and a service to schedule a method from my activity which repeats itself when the phone is in the background, and will pull the user back to the app at set intervals (when the method is executed). I've tried to follow tutorials online but its all been kinda a fuzzy and i'm having trouble doing what i set out to do. Can someone please provide a plain example? i can fill in and figure out the details, i just need to know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schedule your `AlarmManager` to perform your task with your custom interval

```
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(BackgroundReceiver.BROADCAST_ACTION);
    intent.addCategory(BackgroundReceiver.CATEGORY);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, SYNC_REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);

    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeInMillis() + 30000, 30000, alarmIntent);
```

Start your service onReceive intent in `BroadcastReceiver`

```
public class BackgroundReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
        public static String BROADCAST_ACTION = "your.package.ACTION_BACKGROUND";
        public static String CATEGORY = "your.package.CATEGORY_BACKGROUND";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
            Intent downloadIntent = new Intent(context, YourService.class);
            context.startService(downloadIntent);
        }
    }
```

Then process your task in service as per your needs

```
public class YourService extends IntentService{

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            // Process your data whatever you need
        }
    }
```

Register your `BroadcastReceiver`, `IntentService` in your `Manifest`. Hope this helps you to start.

Comment: `BackgroundReceiver` is throwing me an error

Comment: ah its cool i got it

Comment: and how do i cancel the alarm manager?

Comment: You can just cancel the same intent using `alarmManager.cancel(alarmIntent)`. Please accept the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Place below code from where you want to start background Service in activity.

```
Intent alarm = new Intent(this, UnboundServiceDemo.class);

pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, alarm, 0);

alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 5000, pendingIntent);
```

it is just sample code .

Comment: I also need a broadcast receiver in place right?

Comment: and this is placed in the activity or the service

Comment: Yes place this code inside activity but i have not tested for broadcast receiver. but i think it would work.

Comment: dont i have to use a service class if i want the app to run in background?